# RS485 receiving data corruption

Tags: stm32, uart, rs485

This was my first topic, [RS485 Tutorial Issue](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/563645/rs485-tutorial-issue?noredirect=1#comment1472481_563645). I referenced because of the schematics.

I solved the problem in above topic, I forgot to pin settings for DE and RE pins.

I have a different problem now.

I have two devices on the Rs485 line, one of them transmits the data, the other receives the data.

Transmitter, transmit rs485TxBuffer, it is include `uint8_t rs485TxBuffer[2]={0xAA,0xBB}`. I expected the receiver to fill the receive buffer with these data. But I have a problem there.

My problem is:
I get receiver side very interesting printing value, I get rxbuffer like this:

```
Received Message From Rs485 line : aa, 00
Received Message From Rs485 line : bb, 00
Received Message From Rs485 line : aa, 00
Received Message From Rs485 line : bb, 00
Received Message From Rs485 line : aa, 00
```

But I expected the message get like this

```
 aa,bb
```

These are my codes:

```
uint8_t rs485TxBuffer[2]={0xAA,0xBB};
uint8_t rs485RxBuffer[2] ={0x00, 0x00};
```

Transmitter codes:

```
while(1){

        RS485_Set_Transmit_Mode();
         while(HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*)rs485TxBuffer, 2) != HAL_OK)
         {
             // ...
         }
         uartReady = RESET;
        while (uartReady != RESET);
}
void RS485_Set_Transmit_Mode(void)
{
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_4, SET); // DE pin
}

void RS485_Set_Receive_Mode(void)
{
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_3, RESET); // RE pin
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_4, RESET); // DE pin

}

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *UartHandle)
{

uartReady = SET;
}

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *UartHandle)
{

uartReady = SET;

}
```

Receiver codes:

```
    while (1)
    {
            RS485_Set_Receive_Mode();
            HAL_Delay(1);
            while (HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*)rs485RxBuffer, 2) != HAL_OK)
            {
                  // ...
            }
            SerialPrint("Received Message From Rs485 line : %02x, %02x\n",rs485RxBuffer[0],rs485RxBuffer[1]);
    }
void RS485_Set_Transmit_Mode(void)
{
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_4, SET); // DE pin
}

void RS485_Set_Receive_Mode(void)
{
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_3, RESET); // RE pin
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_4, RESET); // DE pin

}

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *UartHandle)
{

uartReady = SET;
}

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *UartHandle)
{

uartReady = SET;

}
```

When I didnt use the delay in my function, I didnt get correct values.

How can I solve the receiving values?

```
/* USART2 init function */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the configuration of `huart2`?

Comment: I added end of the topic

Comment: Why do you use the `_IT` implementations of the UART interface instead of the blocking ones?

Comment: I've seen the example used in this way. But since I am new, I am not good at this. How should I use it?

Comment: In your Transmit code you `while (uartReady != RESET);` to wait for the transmit to finish, but you don't do the same in your receive code. This results in your receiver printing the message before the receive is complete. Using the non-`_IT` versions of the HAL functions would work just as well here and you wouldn't need the interrupt callback functions or the `while (uartReady != RESET);` loops.

Comment: @brhans        while(HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, (uint8_t*)rs485RxBuffer,2,100) != HAL_OK);
when I use this function, and than print rs485RxBuffer but I have a corruption again. I get value this :
Received Message From Rs485 line : a7, a7
Received Message From Rs485 line : db, db

Comment: You'll probably find that if you start the receiver running 1st and then start the transmitter that it'll work (at least once). You need to put a delay in your transmit device between transmits because as you have it now, the receiver does not know where the bytes start - all it sees it a stream of bits - so it can't synchronize on the start of a byte properly. If you insert a short delay in your transmitter loop then this gap will allow the receiver to properly synchronize and give you the correct data.

Comment: @brhans thank you so much, now it's working now. So if my device was both a receiver and a transmitter, could I use interrupt?

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to start the receive with interrupt, with set timeout - a timeout timer that restarts at received char. So you should start receive and this should trigger an interrupt when last character is received + timeout_char / or if no character is received + timeout_recv

Then you you have to parse the received telegram by using receive complete callback.

You do wait in endless loop, but the interrupt will call a callback, so no need to wait in loop.

Comment: How can I do, receive with interupt with set timeout ?

Comment: it sounds very complicated, could you give an example,please ?

Comment: @gogogo have a look https://github.com/MaJerle/stm32-usart-uart-dma-rx-tx